# Broken Dependencies Installing NPM on Ubuntu 18.04.3 Server

Tags: dependencies, nodejs, npm

I'm currently attempting to install NPM on an Ubuntu 18.04 Server install, but getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi-color-table but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-underscore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
```

I read somewhere that installing libssl1.0-dev would solve the problem, but that hasn't fixed it for me. Any advice?

**EDIT:** I was following directions from GitHub linked on NodeJS's website that had me using curl and whatnot. I reverted my VM to a snapshot and tried just installing NodeJS and NPM from the repos and it seems to work fine. Problem solved, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already solved this by reverting the VM using a snapshot but in the future you can check what dependencies are required by doing after installing the repo:

```
apt update
apt-cache depends nodejs
```

It'll return this:

```
$ apt-cache depends nodejs
nodejs
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: libstdc++6
  Depends: python-minimal
  Depends: ca-certificates
  Conflicts: nodejs-dev
  Conflicts: <nodejs-legacy>
  Conflicts: npm
  Replaces: nodejs-dev
  Replaces: <nodejs-legacy>
    nodejs
  Replaces: npm
```